# What is this word in a sample of blackletter script?

Tags: history, middle-english

What is this word "seneney"? Am I right?

[image]

Comment: Note that you should have said that you were quoting from the Bible, and given book/chapter/verse.

Comment: Is this even in English?

Comment: @JJJ Yes, Wycliffe published on the cusp of [Early Middle English](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Middle_English#Early_Middle_English) becoming Late Middle English. Adding the tag might help future visitors.

Comment: @Andrew Leach. Ah, Middle Middle English.

Comment: @AndrewLeach - In other words, Muddle English.

Comment: Close-voters: there is no commonly-available reference which contains the word *seneney* or *seveney* or even *senevey,* once that word has been identified. Also, the OP may not have known that the excerpt came from Wycliffe's Bible. If he did, he certainly should have said so, but it's not for someone else to take that out of an answer. I'm reopening and rolling back that edit.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This is Matthew 13:31

> ... put before them, and said: “The kingdom of heaven is like a mustard seed that a man took and sowed in his field. Which is the least of all seeds but when it is grown...”

The quoted script appears to be from Wycliffe's Bible of 1395, which is online via [Studylight.org](https://www.studylight.org/desk/index.cgi?sr=0&old_q=Matthew+13&search_form_type=general&q1=Matthew+13%3A31&s=2&t1=en_wyc&ns=0):

> Another parable Jhesus puttide forth to hem, and seide, The kyngdom of heuenes is lijk to a corn of seneuey, which a man took, and sewe in his feeld.

They have (in modern letters) *senevey* which can be found in [OED](https://www.oed.com/view/Entry/176089?redirectedFrom=senevey#eid) as ***senvy:***

> *Obsolete.*
>
> 1. The mustard plant: see ᴍᴜsᴛᴀʀᴅ *n.* 2.
>
> Etymology: < Old French *senevé,* also *-vei, -vel, -vil* (modern French *sénevé*) < popular Latin **sināpātium, < sināpi* mustard.

Comment: +1 nice catch...

Comment: Shouldn't that be "... **toke** and sewe in his **feld**"?

Comment: I quoted the website. Note that printing only started in England in 1476, so there may well be inconsistencies between different copies of Wycliffe's Bible.